# Print menu from json with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, materialize

I'm trying to print a menu from a JSON file but the drop down menu does not work.

[image]

**JSON**

```
[{
    "Opcion": "Solicitud",
    "Nombre": "<a href=\"#/solicitud\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">flight</i>Solicitud</a> ",
    "Descripcion": "Formulario para Solicitud",
    "Submenu": []
}, {
    "Opcion": "Consultas",
    "Nombre": "<a href=\"#/consulta\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">search</i>Consultas</a> ",
    "Descripcion": "Formulario para Consultas",
    "Submenu": []
}, {
    "Opcion": "Transferencia",
    "Nombre": "<a href=\"#/transferencia\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">attach_money</i>Transferencia</a> ",
    "Descripcion": "Transferencia",
    "Submenu": []
}, {
    "Opcion": "Administracion",
    "Nombre": "<a class=\"dropdown-button\" data-activates=\"administracion\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">settings</i>Administracion<i class=\"material-icons right\">arrow_drop_down</i></a> ",
    "Descripcion": "Menu de Administracion",
    "Submenu": [{
        "Opcion": "Reservas",
        "Nombre": "#/reservas ",
        "Descripcion": "Reservas",
        "Submenu": null
    }, {
        "Opcion": "Globales",
        "Nombre": "#/globales ",
        "Descripcion": "Globales",
        "Submenu": null
    }, {
        "Opcion": "Convenios",
        "Nombre": "#/convenios ",
        "Descripcion": "Convenios",
        "Submenu": null
    }, {
        "Opcion": "Aplicacion",
        "Nombre": "#/aplicacion ",
        "Descripcion": "Aplicacion",
        "Submenu": null
    }]
}]
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat=" item in menu" ng-bind-html="item.Nombre" ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth">
   <!--class="waves-effect waves-light"-->
   <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="administracion" class="dropdown-content">
      <li ng-repeat="items in item.Submenu"><a href="#/reservas">Reservas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/reservas">Reservas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/globales">Globales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/convenios">Convenios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/aplicacion">Aplicaciones</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I'm using angularjs 1.3.16 and the frontend materializecss

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? How the result differs from the expected behavior?

Comment: Hello jbmartinez, if you look at the image below, get the menu "management" but the drop does not work, it does not appear, if I do it manually if it works but with no work ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth" class="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'dropdown-button' : ''}}" data-activates="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'administracion' : ''}}">
    <span ng-bind-html="item.Nombre"></span>
    <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="administracion" class="dropdown-content">
      <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Submenu"><a ng-href="{{subItem.Nombre}}" ng-bind-html="subItem.Descripcion"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Since you're using [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/), make sure you take these steps to make the submenu working:

- Include jQuery: Navbar dropdowns depends on jQuery.
- Include Materialize minified JavaScript
- Apply classes accordingly: The item which activates the dropdown must have the `dropdown-button` class. The `ul` containing submenu items must have the `dropdown-content` class and an unique id
- The `dropdown-button` element must have the `data-activates` attribute equals to the id of the `ul` containing the submenu items

Finally, include this piece of code to activate the dropdowns:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();     
});
```

I'd suggest using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) instead of Materialize CSS when you're working with Angular apps.

Below is the working snippet. I didn't use `ng-bind-html` in the example in order to avoid injecting the `$sanitize` service (not included in angular core):

```js
var exampleApp = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

  exampleApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.menu = [{
        "Opcion": "Solicitud",
        "Nombre": "<a href=\"#/solicitud\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">flight</i>Solicitud</a> ",
        "Descripcion": "Formulario para Solicitud",
        "Submenu": []
        }, {
        "Opcion": "Consultas",
        "Nombre": "<a href=\"#/consulta\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">search</i>Consultas</a> ",
        "Descripcion": "Formulario para Consultas",
        "Submenu": []
        }, {
        "Opcion": "Transferencia",
        "Nombre": "<a href=\"#/transferencia\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">attach_money</i>Transferencia</a> ",
        "Descripcion": "Transferencia",
        "Submenu": []
        }, {
        "Opcion": "Administracion",
        "Nombre": "<a class=\"dropdown-button\" data-activates=\"administracion\"><i class=\"material-icons left\">settings</i>Administracion<i class=\"material-icons right\">arrow_drop_down</i></a> ",
        "Descripcion": "Menu de Administracion",
        "Submenu": [{
            "Opcion": "Reservas",
            "Nombre": "#/reservas ",
            "Descripcion": "Reservas",
            "Submenu": null
        }, {
            "Opcion": "Globales",
            "Nombre": "#/globales ",
            "Descripcion": "Globales",
            "Submenu": null
        }, {
            "Opcion": "Convenios",
            "Nombre": "#/convenios ",
            "Descripcion": "Convenios",
            "Submenu": null
        }, {
            "Opcion": "Aplicacion",
            "Nombre": "#/aplicacion ",
            "Descripcion": "Aplicacion",
            "Submenu": null
        }]
        }];
}]);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();     
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller" class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" class="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'dropdown-button' : ''}}" data-activates="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'administracion' : ''}}">
      <span ng-bind-html="item.Nombre"></span>
      <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="administracion" class="dropdown-content">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Submenu"><a ng-href="{{subItem.Nombre}}" ng-bind-html="subItem.Descripcion">{{subItem.Descripcion}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Cristian I edited the answer and included a working snippet. I hope it's useful

Comment: Hello jbmartinez, what you wear is just what I need, what's weird is that I spend my project and it does not work, but you say you do not use "ng-bind-html" but if I stop using it gives me error, not if you have something to do I use your angular 1.3.16 and you angular 1.2.26 do not know if that has something to do.

It is quite rare.

Comment: if I delete 'ngSanitize' then I get the following error, "Error: [$ sce: unsafe]. Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context"

The strange thing is that you do not use and do not generate an error, it will be the version of angularjs?

Comment: I'm not leaving it just works for me, it occurs to me, have something to do that I do not read that data in a json json file if you send me a webservice?It will be something runtimes?

Comment: @Cristian I didn't use `ng-bind-html` in the bottom snippet because I didn't want to import non-core modules, but you can use it and it should work. The first block of code has `ng-bind-html` and it should work. The important bit is following the tips in the bullet list.

Comment: @Cristian I added `ng-bind-html`. I had to add a span because `ng-bind-html` overwrites the submenu contents. It looks much better too

Comment: I see that when I use web api fails, if I put the json in a variable, if it works well, it is as if they paint the html before they finish consuming WebAPI is strange.
You have no idea if that happens ?, may be delayed a little show interface?

Comment: @Cristian Remember that http requests are asynchronous, so probably the app is rendering the menu before the data is ready. But I'm just guessing, it depends on your code. Delaying the interface is bad from the user perspective

Comment: @Cristian It may be better you post a new question if you're stuck with that issue, to keep the things organized

Comment: outch !! I did not know that was bad, but then what would be good practice for this?
This is my Controller

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Slkk48GRxR7KraJqC5w6?p=catalogue)

Comment: actually the first menu is the one that will use the second is that I had before but does not work, the first thing you see is what helped me and I will use.

Answer (score 0):

- Try and change the `ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0"` **to** `ng-if="item.Submenu"`
- **or** add another property to the `submenu` e.g. `show = true`, then use `ng-if="item.submenu.show"`.

Comment: Hello Lior G, I just try as you indicate and still does not work, the submenu still not activated